# Парсер SimpleXML

Tags: php, парсер, xmlparser

Помогите, пожалуйста. Как получить содержимое тэга price если известено содержимое тэга name. Мои потуги:

```
<?php
 $title = "item-name"
 $stocks = simplexml_load_file('http://website.com/upload/stocks.xml');
 $stocks = $stocks->xpath('/item/[name=$title]/price');
 foreach($stocks as $stock) {
  echo $stocks->price;
 }
?>
```

XML-файл:

```
<data vendor="SONEX" date="2016-10-28T18:07:45">
<items>
 <item>
  <name>2590/2W</name>
  <price>2675</price>
 </item>
 <item>
  <name>2599</name>
  <price>53845</price>
 </item>
 </items>
 </data>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$stocks = simplexml_load_file('http://website.com/upload/stocks.xml');
foreach($stocks->items->item as $stock) {
   if ($stock->name == "какое-то значение") {
       echo $stock->price
   }
}
```

Comment: не совсем. наверное должно быть `if ($stock->name == "какое-то значение") echo $stock->price;`

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, если уж автор не сможет применить конструкцию `if` самостоятельно, то в программировании ему делать нечего :). Но для чистоты ответа добавлю ваше примечание

Answer (score 0):

Наверно лучше обратится сразу по структуре

```
$title = "item-name";
$stocks = simplexml_load_file('http://website.com/upload/stocks.xml');
echo $stocks->items->item[0]->price;
```